# How do I fit a long frame title into a line?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I use the command `\resizebox` to fit a long frame title into a line, but it doesn't works as shown in the following figure.

[image]

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\title{title}
\author{author}

%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{very very very very long frame title}}
very very very very long frame title
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you given `\begin{frame}{\Huge very very very very long frame title}` a try?

Comment: I think the `sep` space defined  inside `beamercolorbox` which contain the frametitle cause  this problem, try with `\resizebox{\dimexpr\paperwidth - 4ex}{!}{\centering very very very very long frame title}`

Comment: @SparkandShine Did the comments solve your problem?

Comment: @SalimBou Would you like to convert you comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter, yes it did solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Converting [@Salim Bous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275652/how-do-i-fit-a-long-frame-title-into-a-line#comment663409_275652) into a CW answer:**

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\title{title}
\author{author}

%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{\resizebox{\dimexpr\paperwidth - 4ex}{!}{\centering very very very very long frame title}}
very very very very long frame title
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]